# Resizing Layer Panel in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, panel

How do I make the Layer and Layers Order boxes of a usable size in QGIS.  They come up as very small boxes.  All other panels appear to work OK  I use a Mac running High Sierra

Comment: Click the corners and drag then larger.

Comment: I have tried that and it does not work!

Comment: Have you updated your QGis?

Comment: Have updated because I had a problem with an earlier (2.18) version

Comment: Could you install the latest 2.18 in order to check whether it solves your old problem?

Comment: What if you drag and drop the layers panel on top of one of the other panels? Does it take on the size of the other panel?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a bug. There's an ongoing project to correct the many [MacOS-specific issues](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&set_filter=1&f%5B%5D=status_id&op%5Bstatus_id%5D=o&f%5B%5D=cf_2&op%5Bcf_2%5D=~&v%5Bcf_2%5D%5B%5D=MacOS&f%5B%5D=&c%5B%5D=tracker&c%5B%5D=status&c%5B%5D=priority&c%5B%5D=subject&c%5B%5D=assigned_to&c%5B%5D=updated_on&c%5B%5D=cf_2&group_by=) in QGIS. You can help by [making a bug report](http://issues.qgis.org).

Similar outstanding issues include:

- [Tiny Identify Results Window](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20380)
- [GUI bug: Layer Properties -> Attributes Form](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20545)
- [Floating windows cannot be scaled QGIS 3.4.1 macOS (10.11.6)](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20477)